# Using Select Case when with null values

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to populate a column (2003_revenue) with the sum of two columns, STB and Addon that exist in the temp table #CombinedRevTable_2003. However, if both STB and Addon are null, I want to populate the column with Null.

I keep getting an error with my code that there is incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

```
UPDATE data.revenuesummary
SET 2003_Revenue = (
    SELECT CASE 
      WHEN (STB IS NULL AND Addon IS NULL) THEN NULL 
      ELSE SUM(ISNULL(STB,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Addon,0)) 
    FROM #CombinedRevTable_2003 b
    WHERE b.ID = data.revenuesummary.ID
)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an END for the CASE statement

```
UPDATE data.revenuesummary
SET 2003_Revenue = (
    SELECT CASE 
      WHEN (STB IS NULL AND Addon IS NULL) THEN NULL 
      ELSE SUM(ISNULL(STB,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(Addon,0))
    END
    FROM #CombinedRevTable_2003 b
    WHERE b.ID = data.revenuesummary.ID
)
```